# log4j issues, or jboss issues. i almost gave up

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, jboss

I have the following situation: 
- two HA singleton apps on jboss eap 
- each one with its own log4j.properties file:
App1:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, App1

log4j.appender.App1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.App1.append=true
log4j.appender.App1.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/App1.log
log4j.appender.App1.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.App1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.App1.threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.App1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.App1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] [%t] %d{yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} (%C:%F:%L) - %m%n


log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, App1
log4j.logger.com.arjuna=DEBUG, App1
log4j.logger.com.sun=ERROR,App1
log4j.logger.com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe=DEBUG,App1
```

App2

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, App2

log4j.appender.App2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.App2.append=true
log4j.appender.App2.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/App2.log
log4j.appender.App2.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.App2.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.App2.threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.App2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.App2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] [%t] %d{yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} (%C:%F:%L) - %m%n


log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, App2
log4j.logger.com.arjuna=DEBUG, App2
log4j.logger.com.sun=ERROR,App2
log4j.logger.com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe=DEBUG,App2
```

both installed and running quite hmmm... with this issue:
All hibernate logs form App2 are written in App1.log
Also all com.sun.xml... logs from App2 are written in App1.log.
And non (nor hibernate nor sun.xml) are written into App2.log.

Both org.hibernate and com.sun are log managed into applications, at server level they are on ERROR level, so there is no logging in server.log.

Also, if I’m disabling App1, those two categories from App2 will be logged into the App1's log file.

It clearly is something I miss and/or I really don't know.
Now, my problem is that I need log4j to log stuff only where I’m telling it to do it.
Can anyone advise me with anything? And, hmm, I really don’t like the idea of using jboss logging settings (custom appenders in console or standalone-ha.xml).
I just want to use log4j…
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is shipped with JBoss (under modules\system\layers\base\org\hibernate) and uses internally `org.jboss.logging`. And `org.jboss.logging` is also shipped with JBoss. Hence I guess that logging initialization is only done once for the complete JVM (as `org.jboss.logging` is loaded through the module classloader and not through your application class loaders and static fields are classloader specific).

I would recommend (although your requirements sounds strange to me), to ship Hibernate and log4j in your application (i.e. in the lib/ folder of your applications). Then Hibernate is loaded twice, one time by the classloader for the first application and a second time by the classloader for the second application. This way the static field can exist twice.